# Project file management

Tags: product-management

Our team has been working on a new game project and I want to create something where we all can upload files/art/work we do for the game, download content, comment, leave notes and do such things whenever we want. We've been using Google Drive but it's insufficient for us.

We have a Ubuntu server and I wonder if there's something for project management and file sharing application that I could install on the server. I've been told to use Perforce but I want to hear opinions of others.

We're actually using Trello for project management, we're just looking for something where we can upload project files and download them easily. (If possible, downloading/uploading via CLI could be really nice too!)

Comment: I'm not seeing a question, here.

Comment: With some improvements, this question  is likely on topic on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Comment: What are your specific requirements that gdrive cannot meet?